# IP Allowlist in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am aware of the Login whitelisting as documented [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_ip_whitelist.htm&type=5) which basically allows us to provide a single/range of IP addresses from which we can allow our users to login to our MC instance.

## Can anyone explain the concept of **IP Allowlist** explained [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_ip_addresses_for_inclusion.htm&type=5) in official documentation.

- Where to configure these provided list of IP addresses.
- What is the PRO n CONS of this feature.
- Can this be enabled/disabled on platform? or should reach Support team do to so!

An illustration/diagrammatic explanation would help many to understand this concept.

Comment: This is the list of IPs that SDMC uses to function, the idea is on your network you would grant these IP allow list to ensure nothing is blocked due to your network configuration. There is nothing for support to enable/disable

Comment: @EazyE thank you for letting me know the above details. So basically this is a setting needs to be done by an Organizations Network administrator right... And NO action need to be taken either from Marketing Cloud administrator or Sales Cloud administrator.